# Long Polling: Why do some messages come in twice?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, chat, long-polling

I'm currently building a chat application with log polling.
The prototype is located here: http://chat.alexanderjank.de

On server side PHP is used. But I think it's a javascript issue, that some messages come in a couple of times.

The javascript code which is used is:

```
var t;
var xhr;
var ids = [];
var panel = $('#posts-panel');

var indexOf = function(needle) {
    if(typeof Array.prototype.indexOf === 'function') {
        indexOf = Array.prototype.indexOf;
    } else {
        indexOf = function(needle) {
            var i = -1, index = -1;

            for(i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                if(this[i] === needle) {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return index;
        };
    }

    return indexOf.call(this, needle);
};

function getNewPosts(timestamp) {
  xhr = $.ajax({
    url: 'chat.php',
    data: 'timestamp=' + timestamp,
    dataType: 'JSON',
})
  .done(function(data) {
    clearInterval( t );
    // If there was results or no results
    // In both cases we start another AJAX request for long polling after 1 second
    if (data.message_content == 'results' || data.message_content == 'no-results') {
        t = setTimeout(function() { getNewPosts(data.timestamp); }, 1000);
        // If there was results we will append it to the post div
        if (data.message_content ==  'results') {
            // Loop through each post and output it to the screen
            $.each(data.posts, function(index, val) {
               if(indexOf.call(ids, val.msg_id) == '-1') {
                    ids.push(val.msg_id);
                    $('<li class="media"><div class="media-body"><div class="media"><a class="pull-left" href="#"><img class="media-object img-circle " src="assets/img/user.png" /></a><div class="media-body" >'+val.message_body+'<br /><small class="text-muted">Alex Deo | '+ val.posted_time +'</small><hr /></div></div></div></li>').appendTo('.posts');
                    panel.scrollTop(panel[0].scrollHeight);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(function() {
        $('#posts-panel').jScrollPane({
        horizontalGutter:5,
        verticalGutter:5,
        'showArrows': false
        });
    });

    $('.jspDrag').hide();
    $('.jspScrollable').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).find('.jspDrag').stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow');
    });
    $('.jspScrollable').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).find('.jspDrag').stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow');
    });


    if (!Date.now) {
        Date.now = function() { return new Date().getTime(); };
    }

    panel.scrollTop(panel[0].scrollHeight);

    // Create an AJAX request to the server for the first time to get the posts
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: 'chat.php?full_page_reload=1',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        // Assign the this variable to the server timestamp
        // that was given by the PHP script
        serverTimestamp = data.timestamp;
        if(data.posts != 'nothing') {
             $.each(data.posts, function(index, val) {
                    ids.push(val.msg_id);
                    $('<li class="media"><div class="media-body"><div class="media"><a class="pull-left" href="#"><img class="media-object img-circle " src="assets/img/user.png" /></a><div class="media-body" >'+val.message_body+'<br /><small class="text-muted">Alex Deo | '+ val.posted_time +'</small><hr /></div></div></div></li>').appendTo('.posts');
                    panel.scrollTop(panel[0].scrollHeight);
            });
        }
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert('There was an error!');
    });
    // When the form is submitted
    $('#sendMessage').on('submit', function(event) {
        // xhr.abort();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'chat.php?post=1',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: $('#sendMessage').serialize()
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            // Reset the form values
            $('#sendMessage')[0].reset();
        })
        .fail(function() {
            // When there was an error
            alert('An error occured');
        });
        // Prevent the default action
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    // Start the actual long polling when DOM is ready
    getNewPosts(serverTimestamp);
});
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: BTW: This is _normal polling_, not [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling)

Comment: @hindmost Not on server side. The server keeps the connection open till it's got a new message from database via polling the database every second. But it closes the connection with a heartbeat, wehn it hasn't recieved a new message frow database in 15 seconds.

Comment: A way to ensure it won't appear twice would be to check using an ID, as to say if this message ID is already on the page do not add it again. I see you already have an ID in the response, so will be pretty straight forward to do that.

Comment: Spotted a missing assignment perhaps on  `setTimeout(getNewPosts(data.timestamp), 1000);` you may need to add `t = setTimeout(getNewPosts(data.timestamp), 1000);` since you are clearing the interval `clearInterval( t );` just before that.

Comment: Try `setTimeout(function() { getNewPosts(data.timestamp) }, 1000);`

Comment: Ok. I'm now trying to check if its already in the dom or not. Therefor I use an array which will store all ids of the messages in the dom. If a new message should be appended, it checks if it's already in ids and appends it if it's not in ids.

Comment: I think I've now solved. You could check it if you want ;) Thanks to @Filype and dfsq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to ensure a message won't appear twice is to check the presence of that message in the DOM using an ID, within the loop function you already have:

```
$.each(data.posts, function(index, val) {
    if(!$('#message-'+val.id).length) {
        // Add message to the DOM
    }
});
```

If the message is already in the DOM, it will not be added again. I see you already have an ID in the response, so will be pretty straight forward to do that.

Comment: Perfect solution, im just curious if an explanation was ever realised for the cause? Or is just another javascript marvel?